# novice asks: How to do "cvs release" in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, cvs, eclipse-cdt

I'm a novice to Eclipse CDT and its UI for CVS.

In command-line CVS, "cvs release" undoes the effect of "cvs checkout".
http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs_16.html#SEC156

How do I "release" a checkout in Eclipse CDT?

Thanks!

EDIT: I guess you could do it like this:
  1. Eclipse: Delete project
  2. In shell, run

```
% cvs release workspace/project  
% rm -rf workspace/project
```

But resorting to the command line isn't so nice for a GUI IDE.

Comment: Folks are still using cvs release? What's the use case?

Comment: Are you asking for the use case of CVS or of the "cvs release" command?

Use case for CVS: I'm just a programmer; I don't make the decision on which RCS to use.

Use case for CVS release: it's described in the manual page I linked in the OP.

Comment: I meant specifically the "cvs release" subcommand. I still use CVS for a lot of projects. I understand what cvs release does, but I'm wondering why one would think to use it. Are you reading/parsing the history file to look for the effects of the release command?

Comment: wellllll.... I have checked out, abandoned, then checked out another version to the same path... then I looked at the history file once a long time ago and said to myself "OMG, a record the checkouts that I abandoned are still here. It would be better to note that those checkouts have been abandoned, and my directories now contain totally different versions."

So it was a habit from then on to be "squeaky clean" and always "release" my abandoned checkouts. But, if it's just a matter of history, I suppose I could abandon my habit.